# Как грациозно заменить document root для Zend2 с public на public_html?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2, zend2

будет ли кошерно создать символическую ссылку с `public_html` на `public`?

Comment: А собственно, что мешает положить все публичные файлы в public_html ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, ничего не мешает хранить все публичные файлы в папке с любым именем, Zend2 никаких ограничений на название публичной папки не накладывает